# Get longest substring between two strings

Tags: c#, string, substring

I have two words,

`britanicaeng`  and
`britanicahin`

I need to find out the longest common word between these i.e, `britanica`.

How can I do this in C# ?

Comment: common word as in actual word or just sequence of characters?

Comment: [Longest common substring problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_common_substring_problem)

Comment: This is a "well known" problem but I think I'd start here:

http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/21252/longest-common-substring

Comment: Check if this can help you - http://botw3.wordpress.com/2009/09/28/c-longest-common-substring-of-two-strings/

Comment: Check out [this excellent example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77942555/8644294) that explains it very well.

Answer (score 2):

Try this method:

```
public static string FindLongestCommonSubstring(string s1, string s2)
{
    int[,] a = new int[s1.Length + 1, s2.Length + 1];
    int row = 0;    // s1 index
    int col = 0;    // s2 index

    for (var i = 0; i < s1.Length; i++)
        for (var j = 0; j < s2.Length; j++)
            if (s1[i] == s2[j])
            {
                int len = a[i + 1, j + 1] = a[i, j] + 1;
                if (len > a[row, col])
                {
                    row = i + 1;
                    col = j + 1;
                }
            }

    return s1.Substring(row - a[row, col], a[row, col]);
}
```

Usage example:

```
Console.WriteLine(FindLongestCommonSubstring("britanicaeng", "britanicahin"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored the C++ code from Ashutosh Singh at https://iq.opengenus.org/longest-common-substring-using-rolling-hash/ to create a rolling hash approach in C# - this will find the substring in O(N * log(N)^2) time and O(N) space

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
public class RollingHash
{
    private class RollingHashPowers
    {
        // _mod = prime modulus of polynomial hashing
        // any prime number over a billion should suffice
        internal const int _mod = (int)1e9 + 123;
        // _hashBase = base (point of hashing)
        // this should be a prime number larger than the number of characters used
        // in my use case I am only interested in ASCII (256) characters
        // for strings in languages using non-latin characters, this should be much larger
        internal const long _hashBase = 257;
        // _pow1 = powers of base modulo mod
        internal readonly List<int> _pow1 = new List<int> { 1 };
        // _pow2 = powers of base modulo 2^64
        internal readonly List<long> _pow2 = new List<long> { 1L };

        internal void EnsureLength(int length)
        {
            if (_pow1.Capacity < length)
            {
                _pow1.Capacity = _pow2.Capacity = length;
            }
            for (int currentIndx = _pow1.Count - 1; currentIndx < length; ++currentIndx)
            {
                _pow1.Add((int)(_pow1[currentIndx] * _hashBase % _mod));
                _pow2.Add(_pow2[currentIndx] * _hashBase);
            }
        }
    }

    private class RollingHashedString
    {
        readonly RollingHashPowers _pows;
        readonly int[] _pref1; // Hash on prefix modulo mod
        readonly long[] _pref2; // Hash on prefix modulo 2^64

        // Constructor from string:
        internal RollingHashedString(RollingHashPowers pows, string s, bool caseInsensitive = false)
        {
            _pows = pows;
            _pref1 = new int[s.Length + 1];
            _pref2 = new long[s.Length + 1];

            const long capAVal = 'A';
            const long capZVal = 'Z';
            const long aADif = 'a' - 'A';

            unsafe
            {
                fixed (char* c = s)
                {
                    // Fill arrays with polynomial hashes on prefix
                    for (int i = 0; i < s.Length; ++i)
                    {
                        long v = c[i];
                        if (caseInsensitive && capAVal <= v && v <= capZVal)
                        {
                            v += aADif;
                        }
                        _pref1[i + 1] = (int)((_pref1[i] + v * _pows._pow1[i]) % RollingHashPowers._mod);
                        _pref2[i + 1] = _pref2[i] + v * _pows._pow2[i];
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // Rollingnomial hash of subsequence [pos, pos+len)
        // If mxPow != 0, value automatically multiply on base in needed power.
        // Finally base ^ mxPow
        internal Tuple<int, long> Apply(int pos, int len, int mxPow = 0)
        {
            int hash1 = _pref1[pos + len] - _pref1[pos];
            long hash2 = _pref2[pos + len] - _pref2[pos];
            if (hash1 < 0)
            {
                hash1 += RollingHashPowers._mod;
            }
            if (mxPow != 0)
            {
                hash1 = (int)((long)hash1 * _pows._pow1[mxPow - (pos + len - 1)] % RollingHashPowers._mod);
                hash2 *= _pows._pow2[mxPow - (pos + len - 1)];
            }
            return Tuple.Create(hash1, hash2);
        }
    }

    private readonly RollingHashPowers _rhp;
    public RollingHash(int longestLength = 0)
    {
        _rhp = new RollingHashPowers();
        if (longestLength > 0)
        {
            _rhp.EnsureLength(longestLength);
        }
    }

    public string FindCommonSubstring(string a, string b, bool caseInsensitive = false)
    {
        // Calculate max neede power of base:
        int mxPow = Math.Max(a.Length, b.Length);
        _rhp.EnsureLength(mxPow);
        // Create hashing objects from strings:
        RollingHashedString hash_a = new RollingHashedString(_rhp, a, caseInsensitive);
        RollingHashedString hash_b = new RollingHashedString(_rhp, b, caseInsensitive);

        // Binary search by length of same subsequence:
        int pos = -1;
        int low = 0;
        int minLen = Math.Min(a.Length, b.Length);
        int high = minLen + 1;
        var tupleCompare = Comparer<Tuple<int, long>>.Default;
        while (high - low > 1)
        {
            int mid = (low + high) / 2;
            List<Tuple<int, long>> hashes = new List<Tuple<int, long>>(a.Length - mid + 1);
            for (int i = 0; i + mid <= a.Length; ++i)
            {
                hashes.Add(hash_a.Apply(i, mid, mxPow));
            }
            hashes.Sort(tupleCompare);
            int p = -1;
            for (int i = 0; i + mid <= b.Length; ++i)
            {
                if (hashes.BinarySearch(hash_b.Apply(i, mid, mxPow), tupleCompare) >= 0)
                {
                    p = i;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if (p >= 0)
            {
                low = mid;
                pos = p;
            }
            else
            {
                high = mid;
            }
        }
        // Output answer:
        return pos >= 0
            ? b.Substring(pos, low)
            : string.Empty;
    }
}
```